# Can a patient in a medical case report be a co-author?

Tags: authorship, medicine

Individual patient case reports are commonly published in medical journals. I'm wondering in a situation where the patient themself is directly engaged in gathering data and finding a diagnosis, is it possible that the patient might participate in writing the case report and being listed as a co-author? Or is that considered a conflict of interest of some sort, or not allowed for some other reason?

This question is related but not the same as [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/183798/writing-a-case-report-about-my-own-medical-problems-without-treating-physician), where a medical postdoctoral worker asked about writing their own case report alone after all their treating doctors declined. In this case I'm assuming that treating doctors are still involved and one is the lead author. (Answers to that other question only address the issue of IRB approval, which I'd assume is not a problem for the present question.)

Comment: Hmm. Sometimes linguistic consultants are co-authors, but I was recently reading a case report (kinda) where the patient definitely was not. Curious what the medical experts here say.

Comment: Urey and Failla's paper (well, short note) on 'Concerning the Taste of Heavy Water' (http://www.jstor.org/stable/1660704) may well count. Of course, this was well before IRB approvals were sought (1935).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. I have witnessed it multiple times.
Some journals (https://journals.sagepub.com/home/jpx) even have specific formats for this. Another example is the so-called "Patient Self-Reported Outcomes" type, that is offered by some journals, for example: https://ijdrp.org/index.php/ijdrp/about/submissions. I do not see a conflict of interest here, as long as the case report does not claim that a specific therapeutic intervention might be generalizable to a larger patient population.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that having a patient as an author would be ethically acceptable if 2 conditions are met:

1. The offer of authorship does not result in undue influence
2. The author contributed to the academic output significantly enough to warrant authorship

As the [Belmont Report](https://www.hhs.gov/ohrp/regulations-and-policy/belmont-report/read-the-belmont-report/index.html) notes:

> Undue influence, by contrast, occurs through an offer of an excessive, unwarranted, inappropriate or improper reward or other overture in order to obtain compliance.

One might consider authorship as a reward which could influence the participant to consent to the publication of their potentially identifiable information when they otherwise wouldn't. This could be a limited concern if the offer of authorship is made *after* consent has already been obtained.

As always, when considering authorship, academics should consider the contributions of all authors. Agarwal and colleagues have some useful suggestions specifically for case reports (2019. PMID [30756073](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6372049/)).

Additionally, the authors should carefully consider if the patient has any conflict of interest in seeing the results published. If they do, this must be disclosed during publication. I would probably recommend disclosing to the editor of the journal that an author is also the patient, but not necessarily report that in the paper.

I agree that case reports [do not typically require IRB approval](https://www.hopkinsmedicine.org/institutional_review_board/guidelines_policies/guidelines/case_report.html).